# Android Device Monitor not listing processes of attached Device

Tags: android

**ENVIRONMENT**: Windows 10, Android Studio: 1.32, Android Device Monitor (ADM): 24.0.2
**BACKGROUND**: I have two Phones:
-----> Google/Samsung Nexus 4 running Android v4.4.4
-----> Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running Android v5.0.1
Connected via USB.  Developer & Debugging Options are enabled on BOTH phones.

**PROBLEM SUMMARY**: RUNNING PROCESSES ARE NOT BEING SHOWN in ADM

**PROBLEM**: Under Android Device Monitor, I see both the phones listed under Devices tab and both show as ONLINE as follows:

```
> samsung-galaxy_nexus-<serial>      Online          4.4.4, debug
> samsung-sm_n910t-<serial>          Online          5.0.1
```

Note: the second device listed below does not show "debug"

If I click on the carrot under the *"samsung-galaxy_nexus-"* nexus device, I see all the running process. However, if I click on *"samsung-sm_n910t-"* device, I only see:

> ```
>          ?              751      8600
> ```

Why am I not able to see running processes of the second phone? How do I list processes of the other device?